# ASP.NET MVC change default route on login/logout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have a pretty simple requirement.

If the user goes to http://www.somedomain.com/ and is not logged, I want MVC to route user to HomeController.

If the user goes to http://www.somedomain.com/ and is logged in, I want MVC to route user to ClientController.

Is there an easy solution for this problem?

Thank You very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your HomeController, Index action, redirect to the ClientController if the HttpContext.User is not null:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (HttpContext.User != null)
        {
            RedirectToAction("Index", "Client");
        }
    }

}
```

EDIT:  Or Use Request.IsAuthenticated

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            RedirectToAction("Index", "Client");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: With this solution URL is changed, it would be great if URL stayed the same

Comment: I second a request to have the URL unchanged

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few ways to solve this.

Depending on your requirements you could implement an IAuthorizationFilter for this purpose and implement the OnAuthorization method something like this.

```
public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        IUser user = _currentUserProvider.CurrentUser;
        if (user != null)
        {
            // you can perform perform additional user-authorization here...        
            if(_authorizationService.IsAuthorized(user))
            {
               //user is authorized
               return;
            }
            else
            {     
               HandleUnAuthorizedRequest(filterContext);
               return;
            }
        }

        //user is not authenticated (not logged in)
        HandleUnAuthenticatedRequest(filterContext);
    }
```

You then use the actionFilter on your controller method or controller class.
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410209(v=VS.90).aspx for more information about Action Filters.

Now, if you want all unauthenticated requests to go to the ClientController, you can handle the `AuthenticateRequest` event in your `HttpApplication` (usually global.asax.cs) class and implement something like in the actionFilter above.